# jQuery scripts only works on certain pages

Tags: jquery

I'm using Colorbox on my site, and it's working just fine, on most of the pages. But on some, pages, where other jQuery scripts are in use, it fails.

I get this error from the console of IE:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'colorbox'
```

This is the piece that gives me the trouble

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.test').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"75%", top:50, scrolling:false,      onComplete:true});
});
</script>
```

The head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/default/aw_blog/css/style.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/default/onsale/css/product_onsale_label.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/default/onsale/css/category_onsale_label.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/sidenav.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/sidenavcollapse.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/faq/label.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/mageworx/modalbox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/icart.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/prolabel.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/colorbox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/teststore/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/jquery/jquery.1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/jquery/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/aw_onsale/onsale.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/mageworx/modalbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/mageworx/icart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/default/js/sidenavcollapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/default/js/faq/faq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/" />
```

Could it be some kind of conflict?

Comment: It's probably a conflict, but we can't tell from this. You'd have to show us the head of the page on which this is broken so we can see what else is loading. It may also be that jQuery isn't loaded on those pages.

Comment: May want to look at [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I've now added the head from the site. 
The funny thing is that it's only giving me trouble, on certain pages where there's already another jQuery script present. If it matters, it's a Magento shop that I'm running.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a production site with 25 `.js` scripts loaded for one page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of searching through the different pages source code, I found out that multiple magento extensions was loading, a huge variety of different jQuery libs, of all sorts of version..

After commenting all these out, it's working flawless again!

**Note to self, and others, Only 1 jQuery lib!**

Answer (score -1):

More than likely, how does it perform in other browsers, have you tried stripping down to bare minimal code to see how it runs?